# upgrade debian 6

Tags: debian, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I recently found one on my servers installed Debian version 6 :))
Is there any way to upgrade this OS to the new version?
I try to use apt-get update but all the links ignored

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free`

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian squeeze-updates main contrib non-free`

`deb http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates main contrib non-free`

Is there any valid link still working?

Answer (score 6):

Debian releases 6, 7 and 8 have been archived. Try these:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

You may have to deal with expired package signing keys too. Please run the following as a single command line as root:

```
echo 'Acquire::http::archive.debian.org::Verify-Peer "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99archive-cert
```

If using `https` to access the repositories, there might be issues with expired SSL/TLS root certificate, see this link: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1088/how-to-solve-apt-error-server-certificate-verification-failed

Once you've got version 6 up to the archived state, read the release notes for Debian 7 (includes exact steps for upgrading), replace `squeeze` with `wheezy` and run an `apt-get dist-upgrade` or similar. Then read the release notes for Debian 8, replace `wheezy` with `jessie` and repeat.

Each upgrade from one major release to then next may have release-specific steps, so it is **essential** to read the upgrade chapter of the respective release notes. You can't upgrade directly from Debian 6 to Debian 8 or above: only upgrades from a particular release to the immediately following one are supported.

Debian 9 is still available in the normal repository servers in the `oldoldstable` status, so once you get your system to Debian 8, you'll be able to run subsequent upgrades using the normal repository URLs.

Comment: The method described here is correct, but in most cases it's faster to install Debian 11 from stratch.

Comment: In general, agree. Since there are major changes between Debian 6 and the current Debian 11, e.g. the switch to `systemd`,  it would generally be easier and safer to reinstall. But the original poster may not have that option available for some reason, and/or might only want to upgrade up to some specific major version. I gave the procedure; the OP may judge for themselves if it's worth the trouble or not.

Comment: It didn't work, I got this below error same as before
https://paste-bin.xyz/23701

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the security archive needs `squeeze/updates` instead of just `squeeze`. Edited. Also, the command in my second code block should override the GPG `KEYEXPIRED` error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the archive.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ <version> main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ <version> main non-free contrib
```

et cetera.

Alternatively:

- get a large USB disk & mount it (under `/mnt/usb` or something like that)
- download all the ISO's from https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/ onto that disk.
- mount the different ISO images with `sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /mnt/usb/debian-9.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso /mnt/iso` (or the version that you want)
- put `deb file:///mnt/iso stretch main contrib` in your `sources.list`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

and that until you're current.

Comment: It didn't work, I got this below error same as before paste-bin.xyz/23701